# Is there any alternative way for ngUpgrade to Migrate Angularjs to Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

We have an Application which is built using Angularjs. Now I need to Migrate the whole application to angular latest vesrion.

It seems **NgUpgradeModule** supporting hybrid application , but I need to change the whole application to angular.

Is there any option to acheive this?

Comment: What do you mean more precisely by "need to change the whole application to angular"? As in "in one go" , "no mixed AngularJs/ Angular code in the new app"?

Comment: yes, I don't need mixed of AngularJs/Angular code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option is just to create the hybrid Angular / AngularJS application you mentioned, then gradually replace existing AngularJS bits with Angular ones. The advantage with this approach is that you will have an app with 100% of the functionality during the transition.

Comment: You mean, Do I need to Rewrite the full code If I dont need mixed of Angularjs and Angular  ?

Comment: Yes, there's no tool I know of that would just convert your AngularJs app to Angular. https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-from-angularjs-to-angular details the manual steps you might want to consider in the process.

Answer (score 0):

It is no little decision to migrate from AngularJS to Angular. One can influence your business and organization movement, especially when your model relies upon a software application. In this way, you really want an impressive AngularJS to Angular migration plan. This short aide provides you with an outline of what the undertaking resembles, despite the fact that it isn't comprehensive.

You can check this article for more - https://dev.to/bhaviksadhu/how-to-migrate-angularjs-to-angular-2oln